# Pandas DataFrame seems to be skipping columns when a sample is taken?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, pycharm

I'm doing some playing around with python, trying to read a CSV, take 10% of it, and convert to JSON.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

#read excel
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\CSV_1.csv')
#printing this works fine

# Randomly sample 10% of your dataframe
df_10 = df.sample(frac=0.1)
print(df_10) # printing this seems to remove the third column of my csv

#convert excel to json for testing
json_file=df_10.to_json()

print(json_file)
```

Why is the third column of my CSV being removed when I print df_10? It seems to print in a very unexpected manner.

Also, how can I remove the line numbers from my dataframe when it is being read?

Thanks.

Comment: Without any input data, how can we know?

Comment: Please post an small sample file so we can duplicate the problem.